# Disable Range Slider

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a range slider that needs to be disabled. I was not able to find anything on the ionic docs. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**.html**

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-range [(ngModel)]="singleValue" color="danger" pin="true" snaps="true" ></ion-range>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set **`disabled= true;`**

```
 <ion-range disabled="true" [(ngModel)]="singleValue" color="danger" pin="true" snaps="true" ></ion-range>
```

Comment: Thank you again. Your answers are always very helpful.